# System.today() is returning yesterday's date

Tags: apex

My unit test cases were failing.

I was debugging an issue.

I found the root cause as the `System.today()` is returning yesterday's date.

Today is 12 August but `System.today()` is returning **2019-08-11 00:00:00**.

I can resolve this issue by editing my unit test case to get the desired result but have anyone seen something like this?

Comment: Check you locale setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running the test case under a test user.

Like below:

```
User usr = new User(
            UserName = strYourTestMethod + '@xyz.com',
            FirstName = 'Test-First-Name',
            LastName = 'Test-Last-Name',
            isActive = true,
            Alias = 'test',
            Email = strYourTestMethod + '@xyz.com',
            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
            LocalesIdKey = 'en_US',
            TimezonesIdKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
            ProfileId = prof.Id,
            Vantive_Person_ID__c = NewGuid() // strYourTestMethod.left(40)
        );
        insert usr;

System.runAs(usr) {
    System.debug('System.today()=' System.today() );
}
```

As the time zone is Los Angeles, that was the reason `System.today()` was returning 11 August, as it is the time in Los Angeles.

Comment: Inserting user is not required for `System.runAs`

Answer (score 2):

`System.today()` is based on `Timezone` in your `Advanced User Details`.

Change it to correct timezone. Changing it to `GMT +5:30 (Indian Standard Time)` gives `12/Aug/2019`

Answer (score 1):

today():Returns the current date in the current user's time zone.

We set the default Locale for all the users in Company information-->Default Time Zone.
But,The user Locale settings can override the default settings.

Please check on default time zone in company information and the user's locale settings are the same inorder to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Change your time zone to the time zone you are currently residing or want the record date to be based on.

- user settings --> advanced user settings --> locale settings --> change your time zone here.